# Em's margin is different on elements with different font size

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, font-size

I'm working with Zurb Foundation (v4) which is using EMs and not PX.

One down side i found with using EMs is when an element has a margin set by `$column-gutter (e.g. 0.9375em)`
If the element has font size which is NOT 1em (e.g. 0.875em) then the margin on this element is smaller (since ems is relative to the font-size) than an element that its font size is 1em.

So if I have the 2 elements next to each other the actual margin outcome on both is inconsistent.
I really want to keep the margin on elements consistent even if an element has a different font-size.
Is there a smart way to achieve that (without using px)?

Comment: Can you show an example? It sounds like you should simply use a number that takes the font size differences into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EM values are always a multiple of the parent's font size.

For example, if the font-size of the element is 0.875em , then the margin of that element will be multiplied by 0.875. The base font size in Foundation 4 is 16px, therefore the mentioned element's font-size will be 0.875*16 = 14px. The margin is set to 0.9375em, which will be 0.9375*16*0.875=13.125px in this example.

If you want a 15px margin everywhere either always divide it by the parent's font size (in the example by 0.875, so use (0.9375/0.875)EM instead of 0.9375EM), or use REM, which is relative to the base font-size (which is 16px in Foundation 4), so you don't have to deal with the parent's font-size.

If there are more parent elements in the HTML-hierarchy, you need to pay respect to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the unit `rem`, which is similar to `em` but relative to the font size of the root element (`html`).

It does not work on IE8 or lower, unfortunately. But there is a [Polyfill](https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill) for it.

Comment: @AmirSouchami If possible you could use an additional inner element for the content with the different font-size.